# how to check if ms office product is installed and version of it VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, ms-office

I want to find whether ms office is installed and version of it...
how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged it as visual C++, I'm assuming you want to do it in C++.
One way is to parse through the following registry key 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

For e.g.
Enumerate this key and find out if the value `displayname` contains `Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2007`
You may also find the version number in other values like `version`, `versionmajor`, `verisonminor`

FYI you can use this registry key to find out almost any software which 'installs' on your system.

This is only for 32 bit installation though. For 64-bit installation, you'll need to find a similar tree structure inside registry node WOW6432Node.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Office Version Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OfficeVersion.aspx)

> #### How does it work?
>
> The code is based on an outdated Microsoft knowledge base article [Q247985](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247985) (the code in the knowledge base article does not work for Office 2003 or 2007). The code looks for a specific registry key which holds the version for each application (e.g. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Application/CurVer for Excel) which contains the version encoded in a string ("Excel.Application.11" on my computer). The internal Microsoft version number (i.e. the "11" at the end of "Excel.Application.11" ) is then mapped to the external "marketing" name, that you will be more familiar with (e.g. the internal version "11" is more commonly known as "Office 2003").